# Keep image in GridView selected

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

**What I've done:**

---

Hello Guys,
I've got a GrindView which i filled over my Database. Now the Images shows up there and are scrollable. But when I click on it, they don't keep selected. To see which picture is selected I builded a Toastmessage which shows me what picture i clicked on with the onIemClickListner.

**Question:**

---

I'd like to let the Clicked Image, selected. So that you click on time on a Image in the GridView and afterwards it keeps selected.
How can i realize that? I would be happy if there's a tutorial or a codesample, to see how it works.

**The Code**

---

This is what i tried that only the actual image gets keeps selected with the colors but it dosn't work the right way, sometimes it just changes..

```
//Hier wird gemerkt welches bild
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        boolean color = false;
            View old;
            View v;

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View vv, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(SFilterConfigActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                v = vv;

                //gridview.setSelection(position);

               if (color == false){
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                old = v;
                color = true;

               }

               else {
                   old.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                   v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);

                   color = false;

               }
            }
        });
```

Thx for you anwser in advance

safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call setAdapter()

do it like this

setSelection(setSelected, true)

Comment: ok it worked, but how can i set a background color when it keeps selected... (+1 btw for the first working part, if that with the color works to you get a green tick)

Comment: you want to change the color of selected image ??

Comment: in your onItemClickListener()...do .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

Comment: oh dear its that easy? damnt!

Comment: so now it works if i click on it the color changes, but it keeps there even i select an other one, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code.

```
            if (color == false){
                vv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                old = vv;
                color = true;
            } else {
                old.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                vv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                old=vv;
            }
```